# How do I let WordPress Subscriber (default role) upload images to Media Library via ACF frontend form without also getting access to Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, advanced-custom-fields, user-roles, media-library

I have tried using Edit User Roles/Members plugin (latest versions) to give default **Subscriber** role capability to upload images via a front end ACF form. The only way I can do this is Grant 2 permission

1. Upload Files
2. Edit Posts

If I don't grant permission to Edit Posts I get an error message '**An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.'** when attempting to upload an image. If I do grant edit posts permission the user can view the dashboard which I don't want them to do.

Is there an alternative capability I can use so users can upload images via the form but not have access to the dashboard. I have unset most other capabilities.

I am on the current latest version of WordPress 6.2.2 and disabled most of the other plugins and functions apart from the ones vital to the site running

Comment: I think you can't do it using the capabilities, but you can try preventing access to admin pages if user role is subscriber, you can do it in the `admin_init` hook.